# getFragmentManager() not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to launch a DialogFragment that is contained within a library module locally in my project. The class which I'm calling it from is using *Kotlin* and I'm getting the following error on the function *getFragmentManager()*: **None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied**

```
  import com.github.adamshurwitz.materialsearchtoolbar.SearchDialogFragment
    ...

    private var searchDialogFragment: SearchDialogFragment? = null
    ...

    searchDialogFragment = SearchDialogFragment()
    searchDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, null)
```

I have another project where I am calling this in *Java* and it works fine using: *getSupportFragmentManager()*.

Solutions I have tried:

```
searchDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null)
searchDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, null)
searchDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager as FragmentManager, null)
searchDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction(), null)
searchDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager(), null)
```

Comment: what is your `show` method signature?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the supportFragmentManager?

Comment: @VladMatvienko: I'm using the android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment method.

public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        mDismissed = false;
        mShownByMe = true;
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }

Comment: @AdamForbis I tried that method as well.

Comment: If you look at the source of the show method is the tag parameter marked as @Nullable? Does it still do the same thing if you give it an actual tag?

Comment: @AdamForbis: The tag param is not marked as nullable, I added in a String there just to try, but it is the same result.

Comment: What is the class you're trying to do this in extending from?

Comment: @Ascorbin It extends AppCompatActivity()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `searchDialogFragment` variable is marked as nullable with the question mark in the declaration you need to use the safe call operator `?.`. It only executes when `searchDialogFragment` is not null:

```
searchDialogFragment?.show(supportFragmentManager, null)
```

Or you could use the following to declare your variable as not null but still be able to initialize it later in your code:

```
private lateinit var searchDialogFragment: SearchDialogFragment
```

Comment: Thank you Jakob! That fixed it.

Comment: this solution doesn't work with me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405288/supportfragmentmanager-not-working-with-kotlin any help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace with the following code:

```
searchDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction(), null)
```

Be sure if you already imported: `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`